# visual c# 2010 playing sound in form 1 (From resorce file)

Tags: c#, .net, forms, audio

OK i am trying to make my form 1 application play a .wav file i have imported to my resource file i have serched for this online but all i can find is

```
Sub PlayBackgroundSoundFile()
    My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Waterfall.wav", _
        AudioPlayMode.Background) End Sub
```

but  i believe this is for a console application if not not matter where i put the code i get an lots of errors

Here is the code i am working with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myForm = new Form1();
            myForm.Show();




        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private class form1_load
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What do i have  to add and where bare in mind i have never used any method like this before 
if you with to just edit the code the name of the file is sound.wav

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y171b18%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: nope still errors it wants me to generate half the code

Comment: BTW, as far as I know, what you have found is code from Visual Basic.

Answer (score 1):

I just did it myself: created simple form with one button and created event to this button. Contents of Form1 class is:

```
    using System;
    using System.Media;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void btPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string path;
                using (var dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
                {
                    dlg.Multiselect = false;
                    dlg.Filter = "WAV files|*.wav";
                    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel) return;
                    path = dlg.FileName;
                }
                SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(path);
                sp.Play();
            }  
        }
    }
```

And it works perfectly. Try this on, an if you're still gonna be having errors, you could post here which errors exactly. It would help me in helping you.

Comment: thank you for your help i found a solution 'SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.sound);
            player.Play()'